# Obtaining an object identifier in lsfusion

Tags: object, lsfusion

I have a Document class and I have assigned a unique identifier to each object in that class. But I cannot understand how to get the document by its id?

```
CLASS Document;
id(Document d) = DATA INTEGER (Document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `GROUP` operator:

```
document(id) = GROUP MAX Document d BY id(d);
```

or alternatively:

```
document(id) = GROUP AGGR Document d BY id(d);
```

In the latter example a [constraint](https://docs.lsfusion.org/Constraints/) on the uniqueness of the `id` will be created. This will result in an error message if you try to create two documents with the same identifier.